# recursive iterate over json data with no known length and depth

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object, for-loop

Im currently making a chrome app and Im using local storage. Then my backend returns JSON data and then I saved this locally, then I encrypt all items inside this JSON. My problem is I have different sets of JSON and also have different functions to encrypt this.

I was trying to create dynamic function that will return a copy of these sets of JSON data but with each item encrypted, but i cant make it. My JSON consist of arrays and objects.

My question is, is it possible? If so, I need a working sample.

By the way, I'm using angularJS and this is my current code.

```
    // this function  returns a copy of a JSON but with encrypted values.
    // encrypts objectData using base 64
    // param -> objectData = data from database (rater and its ratees)
    fac.encryptData = function(param) {
        var raterObject = param;
        var resultObject = { 'ratees':[] }; // final value will be equivalent to raterObject
        for(property in raterObject) {
            if(raterObject[property] instanceof Array) {
                angular.forEach(raterObject[property], function(ratee, rateeKey) {
                    var rateeObject = { 'competencies':[] };
                    for(property in ratee) {
                        if(ratee[property] instanceof Array) {
                            angular.forEach(ratee[property], function(competency, competencyKey) {
                                var competencyObject = { 'proficiencies':[], 'competencyScoreInfo':[] };
                                for(property in competency) {
                                    if(competency[property] instanceof Array) {
                                        if(property == 'proficiencies') {
                                            angular.forEach(competency[property], function(proficiency, proficiencyKey) {
                                                var proficiencyObject = {};
                                                for(property in proficiency) {
                                                    if(proficiency[property] == null ) {
                                                        proficiency[property] = '';
                                                    }
                                                    if(property != '$$hashKey') {
                                                        proficiencyObject[property] = base64.encode(proficiency[property].toString());
                                                    } else {
                                                        proficiencyObject[property] = proficiency[property];
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                competencyObject.proficiencies.push(proficiencyObject);
                                            });
                                        } else if(property == 'competencyScoreInfo') { // di pa tapos
                                            angular.forEach(competency[property], function(proficiency, proficiencyKey) {
                                                var proficiencyObject = { 'indicators':[], 'c1':[], 'c2':[] };
                                                for(property in proficiency) {
                                                    if(proficiency[property] instanceof Array) {
                                                        if(property == 'indicators') {
                                                            angular.forEach(proficiency[property], function(indicator, indicatorKey) {
                                                                var indicatorObject = {};
                                                                for(property in indicator) {
                                                                    indicatorObject[property] = base64.encode(indicator[property].toString());
                                                                }
                                                                proficiencyObject.indicators.push(indicatorObject);
                                                            });
                                                        } else if (property == 'c1') {
                                                            angular.forEach(proficiency[property], function(valueC1, c1Key) {
                                                                var c1Object = {};
                                                                for(property in valueC1) {
                                                                    c1Object[property] = base64.encode(valueC1[property].toString());
                                                                }
                                                                proficiencyObject.c1.push(c1Object);
                                                            });
                                                        } else if (property == 'c2') {
                                                            angular.forEach(proficiency[property], function(valueC2, indicatorKey) {
                                                                var c2Object = {};
                                                                for(property in valueC2) {
                                                                    c2Object[property] = base64.encode(valueC2[property].toString());
                                                                }
                                                                proficiencyObject.c2.push(c2Object);
                                                            });
                                                        }
                                                    } else {
                                                        proficiencyObject[property] = base64.encode(proficiency[property].toString());
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                competencyObject.competencyScoreInfo.push(proficiencyObject);
                                            });
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        if(property != '$$hashKey') {
                                        // if(property != '$$hashKey' && property != 'commentSituationTask' && property != 'commentAction' && property != 'commentResult') {
                                            competencyObject[property] = base64.encode(competency[property].toString());
                                        } else {
                                            competencyObject[property] = competency[property];
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                rateeObject.competencies.push(competencyObject);
                            });
                        } else {
                            if(property != 'currentPage' && property != '$$hashKey') {
                                rateeObject[property] = base64.encode(ratee[property].toString());
                            } else {
                                rateeObject[property] = ratee[property].toString();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    resultObject.ratees.push(rateeObject);
                });
            } else {
                resultObject[property] = base64.encode(raterObject[property].toString());
            }
        }
        return resultObject;
    };
```

See, i have this function for just encrypting a particular JSON. Then I have another encrypt function for other JSON, so I want to create a dynamic function to encrypt different JSON.

Comment: Yes, this sounds possible. But please show us the code you've tried, and an example input that did not give the expected results.

Comment: @Bergi actually, i didnt try to code it but i tried to think of it and i cant think a solution. but I will edit my question and add my current codes and its problem.

Comment: i would simply stringify the whole thing, and encrypt that to get it all done quickly without loops and while maintaining types.

Comment: wwwait. i dont know that stringify, but i will take a look of it. thanks for the idea.

Comment: @dandavis , thanks a lot for the info. its a lot easier and faster.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
function encryptData(data) {
    var encryptedData = null;
    if (typeof data == 'object') {
        encryptedData = {};
        angular.forEach(data, function (value, key) {
            encryptedData[key] = encryptData(value);
        }
    } else if (data instanceof Array) {
        encryptedData = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            encryptedData.push(encryptData(data[i]));
        }
    } else {
        encryptedData = base64.encode(data.toString());
    }
    return encryptedData;
}
```

Comment: Exlord , sorry but I will not try your answer. @dandavis gave a different approach to solve my problem, its a lot easier and faster. thanks for your answer